# automatic cache deletion in container Mastodon

Tags: docker, mastodon

Tell me how you implemented the automatic deletion of the mastodon cache, via cron directly on the VM itself, or in the container in which the Mastodon application is located, if so, tell me how, thank you!

I implemented this directly through the cron on the VM itself, I wonder if there is a way to do this in a container

Answer (score 1):

There's a simple solution:

use `bind mount` like:

```
docker run ... -v dir/on/host:dir/on/container:rw ...
```

And then, you can use the `cron` from the host.

The `docker` philosophy is to run only the smallest amount of process at the same time.